# How to Get Security Roles of Another User in CRM 2013 Using Javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

Getting current (logged) user security roles from the context is trivial:

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles()
```

But I can't find an answer how to get the roles for another user by Id or Name? (Different from the user who is logged on currently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use odata to get roles assigned to user:

```
http://<server>/<org>/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserRolesSet?$filter=SystemUserId eq guid'<user guid>'
```

in similar way you possibly want to check for roles assigned to teams that user belongs to